# Express.js and Neo4j

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j

I have seen alot of examples of how to integrate express.js and mongodb. Does anyone know a good way to integrate neo4j and express.js?

I have been playing around with node-neo4j and I am able to return cypher queries to the terminal. However, I am confused as to how to post the cypher query, in json format, to the local host.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also see http://neo4j.com/developer/javascript

Answer (score 2):

In order to reply simply to your question, there is an `express` module for Neo4j, here :

http://expressjs.com/guide/database-integration.html#neo4j

It will remove you the burden to format the json correctly for preparing the statements.

Repository is here if you want to see how it is used inside :

https://github.com/hacksparrow/apoc

Maybe you can contribute to it, for the quick look I did, I see that there is no support for 2.2 auth extension, so you may want to make a PullRequest in order to improve the library.

Comment: So my issue with apoc, is that I can not connect it to the neo4j db with the username and password. I was using node-neo4j because it has a authentication, but that does not work well with express.js. Is there a way to wrap the apoc query in the node-neo4j or is there a way to connect to neo4j, using the username and password with apoc?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you can always use passportJS for authentication, it works fine with neo4j